# How do you use Ruby CSV converters?

Tags: ruby, csv

Suppose you have the following file:

```
textfield,datetimefield,numfield
foo,2008-07-01 17:50:55.004688,1
bar,2008-07-02 17:50:55.004688,2
```

The Ruby code to read a .csv is something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'csv'

csv = CSV($stdin, :headers => true, :converters => :all)
csv.each do |row|
  print "#{row}"
  the_date = row['datetimefield'].to_date
end
```

That code gives this error message:

```
./foo2.rb:8:in `block in <main>': undefined method `to_date' for "2008-07-01 17:50:55.004688":String (NoMethodError)
```

What gives?

I've read [the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html), but I don't get it.

**Edit**: Yes, I could parse the fields individually.  The point of this question is that I want to learn how to use the documented converters feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your date times don't match the `CSV::DateTimeMatcher` regexp that CSV uses to decide whether it should attempt a date time conversion. By the looks of it it's doing so because of the fractional seconds you've got.

You could either overwrite that constant or write your own converter (`DateTime.parse` seems happy with your strings)

Comment: Aha, good job.  If I remove the fractional seconds, it works.  Thus, I accept your answer.  This is surprising, since the docs say ":date_time: Converts any field DateTime::parse() accepts." and ":all: All built-in converters. A combination of :date_time and :numeric.".  That is, :all uses :date_time, which uses DateTime.parse(), which you say accepts the fractional seconds.  So, the docs are wrong?  (That is, they claim any DateTime.parse() but actually have a mismatched regex?)

Comment: @dfrankow Nothing wrong with your reasoning. There is a weird regex in csv.rb testing if a string looks like a datetime. It does not reckognize valid dates. I filed a [bug](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5906).

Comment: Another way to put this: The use of :all above is essentially as the docs intend?  (I couldn't find any real examples from Google.)

Comment: @steenslag: +1 to filing a bug.  Good job!

Comment: I landed here because formats like `"03/02/2012"` aren't getting recognized (mm/dd/yyyy instead of yyyy first), and I don't know how to override `DateMatcher` in the docs.

Comment: To close the loop on the bug filed by @dfrankow, the reason OP's original test failed and the reason the bug was rejected is that "03/02/2012" is ambiguous (MM/DD/YYY?  DD/MM/YYYY?) and so ruby does not define a default format for that datetime.

Answer (score 27):

You are asking how to use converters.

My example defines the usage of a new converter `mytime`.
The converter my_time tries to build a time object if possible.

```
#Define test data
src = <<csv
textfield,datetimefield,numfield
foo,2008-07-01 17:50:55.004688,1
bar,2008-07-02 17:50:55.004688,2
csv

require 'csv'
require 'time'
CSV::Converters[:mytime] = lambda{|s| 
  begin 
    Time.parse(s)
  rescue ArgumentError
    s
  end
}

csv = CSV(src, :headers => true, :converters => [:mytime])
csv.each do |row|
  print "#{row}"
  the_date = row['datetimefield'].to_date
end
```

Using this technique, you may also define a converter to create a date from time-like strings. This solution also keeps all other converters.

```
#define test data
src = <<csv
textfield,datetimefield,numfield
foo,2008-07-01 17:50:55.004688,1
bar,2008-07-02 17:50:55.004688,2
csv

require 'csv'
require 'time'
CSV::Converters[:time2date] = lambda{|s| 
  begin 
    Time.parse(s).to_date
  rescue ArgumentError
    s
  end
}

csv = CSV(src, :headers => true, :converters => CSV::Converters.keys + [:time2date])
csv.each do |row|
  print "#{row}"
  p row['datetimefield'] #Date-field
end
```

Answer (score -3):

Works!!! Executable version of code:

```
#Define test data
src =
  "textfield,datetimefield,numfield\n" +
  "foo,2008-07-01 17:50:55.004688,1\n" +
  "bar,2008-07-02 17:50:55.004688,2"

require 'csv'
require 'time'

CSV::Converters[:mytime] = lambda{|s|
  begin
    Time.parse(s)
  rescue ArgumentError
    s
  end
}

csv = CSV(src, :headers => true, :converters => [:mytime])
array_of_hash_objects = csv.to_a.map {|row| row.to_hash }

array_of_hash_objects.each do |row|
  print "#{row}"
  the_date = row['datetimefield'].to_date
  puts
  print the_date
  puts
end

CSV::Converters[:time2date] = lambda{|s|
  begin
    Time.parse(s).to_date
  rescue ArgumentError
    s
  end
}

csv = CSV(src, :headers => true, :converters => CSV::Converters.keys + [:time2date])
array_of_hash_objects = csv.to_a.map {|row| row.to_hash }

array_of_hash_objects.each do |row|
  print "#{row}"
  puts
  p row['datetimefield'] #Date-field
end
```

=============

## Outputs:

```
{"textfield"=>"foo", "datetimefield"=>2008-07-01 17:50:55 -0400, "numfield"=>"1"}
2008-07-01
{"textfield"=>"bar", "datetimefield"=>2008-07-02 17:50:55 -0400, "numfield"=>"2"}
2008-07-02
{"textfield"=>"foo", "datetimefield"=>2008-07-01 17:50:55 -0400, "numfield"=>1}
2008-07-01 17:50:55 -0400
{"textfield"=>"bar", "datetimefield"=>2008-07-02 17:50:55 -0400, "numfield"=>2}
2008-07-02 17:50:55 -0400
```