# Removing carriage returns from CSV columns using converters in Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm trying to remove all line break characters (\n and \r) from within column values on an outbound CSV before its sent. The most straightforward way appears to be with a CSV Converter - however, it doesn't seem to be working for me.

```
csv_options = {}
csv_options[:force_quotes] = true
csv_options[:col_sep] = "|"
CSV::Converters[:remove_newlines] = lambda{|s| 
  begin 
    s.tr("\n","").tr("\r","")
  rescue ArgumentError
    s
  end
}
csv_options[:converters] = [:remove_newlines]
CSV.open(local_file.path, "wb", csv_options) do |csv|
  ...
```

When I test this, the other aspects of `csv_options` (the `:force_quotes` and `:col_sep`) both work, but line breaks within fields still remain. Does anyone have any suggestions? Note that, for various reasons, I can't remove the linebreaks directly in the strings (or anywhere within the `CSV.open` block itself), which is why I'm trying to use the converters.

EDIT: Sharpened up the code a bit based on other users' input, but with the same results. Code I'm using now is:

```
CSV.open(local_file.path, "wb",
          :force_quotes => true,
          :col_sep => "|",
          :converters => lambda { |s| s.tr("\n\r","") }
        ) do |csv|
  ...
```

Comment: Have you tried using the converter lambda directly (rather than trying to add it to `CSV::Converters`)? According to the documentation (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new), the converters option accepts predefined converters (by name), or custom lambdas.

Comment: `tr` does replace multiple chars in one go: `p "aaa\n\rbb".tr("\n\r","")`.

Comment: Hmm, ok, I'll test that @Jeremy. I was referencing off the the second answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903649/how-do-you-use-ruby-csv-converters

Comment: @steenslag I'm looking to replace all instances of \n, and all instances of \r. So I would want "aaa\nbbb\rccc" -> "aaabbbccc"

Comment: @CaptainPlanet `tr("\n\r","")` does exactly that.

Comment: @steenslag ah, gotcha. good to know

Comment: @JeremyLewis I tried with the lambda directly (updated original question with my new code), but still no luck. Code completes without errors, but line breaks are still included in outbound file.

Comment: Can you try "\r\n" instead of "\n\r"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the issue is that you want to convert the output to a file and not the input. The `:converters` option only handles converting input from a CSV file, it doesn't apply the conversions when writing out in CSV format.

If you **really** want this functionality you can monkey patch it in:

```rb
require 'csv'

class CSV
  alias :old_init_separators :init_separators

  def init_separators(options)
    old_init_separators(options)

    if options.delete(:remove_newlines)
      old_quote = @quote
      @quote = lambda do |field|
        old_quote.call(String(field).tr("\r\n", ""))
      end
    end
  end
end

CSV.open('test.csv', 'wb',
         :force_quotes => true,
         :col_sep => '|',
         :remove_newlines => true) do |csv|

  csv << ["A\r\nB", "C\r\nD"]
  csv << ["E\r\nF", "G\r\nH"]

end
```

Note the addition of the `:remove_newlines` option.

```
$ cat test.csv
"AB"|"CD"
"EF"|"GH"
```

Comment: Awesome. And yea, I guess I just misunderstood the functionality of the converters, and assumed they worked both ways. But the approach you gave me worked great, thank you!

Comment: @CaptainPlanet No problem. Please accept it as the answer :).